# using variables in jacl and wsadmin

Tags: scripting, websphere, tcl, wsadmin, jacl

I am trying to use variables in install script in wsadmin on jacl. First I am specifying

```
set nodeName [$AdminControl getNode]
set cellName [$AdminControl getCell]
```

Then in my script I want to use these 2 variables but for some reason it done want to take them

```
$AdminApp install C:/ssc.war { -nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination $(APP_INSTALL_ROOT)/$(CELL) -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -appname ssc_war -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -noenableClientModule -clientMode isolated -novalidateSchema -contextroot /ssc -MapModulesToServers {{"F" ssc.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=$**cellName**,node=$**nodeName**,server=server1}} -MapWebModToVH {{"Fortify Portal" ssc.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host}} -CtxRootForWebMod {{"Fortify Portal" ssc.war,WEB-INF/web.xml /ssc}}}
```

Probably something wrong with the syntax

Answer (score 0):

In the initial script you provided, I don't see any attempt to use the variables `nodeName` or `cellName`.  Also, do you actually care about supplying all of those arguments?  Most of them are defaults.  Also, you're not putting quotes " around the .war path, which is required.

To use a variable in a wsadmin script, put a `$` sign in front of the variable name.  Such as:

```
set myvar "test"
puts $myvar
```

So, to install an app, it should be as simple as:

```
set cellName [$AdminControl getCell]
set nodeName [$AdminControl getNode]
set serverName [$AdminControl getServer]
$AdminApp install "C:/ssc.war" {
    -node $nodeName 
    -cell $cellName 
    -server $serverName
}
```

I'd recommend taking a look at the IBM doc for WebSphere scripting, it describes what you're trying to do: 
[Installing enterprise applications using wsadmin scripting](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html)